# How do I maintain the road's texture after applying the curve modifier to make the road a single object?

Tags: materials, modifiers, bezier-curves

I created a road using a road-textured rectangular plane, bezier curves, an array modifier, and a curve modifier. But when I apply the modifiers to make the road one simple object, the material with the road texture gets applied to the whole road instead of individual faces of the road as it was originally.

[image: before applying modifiers]
[image: after applying modifiers]

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: You could try to assign the intended faces to the road-textured material, and all the other faces to another material. To get better answers, at least a screenshot would help.

Comment: Added screenshots

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used object coordinates for the texture placement. You want to use UV, in the texture properties window make sure you are using UV for mapping. Before applying the modifiers go into edit mode and hit U->Reset. If this doesn't map the faces correctly to the texture, open image editor screen along the 3d view and adjust the UVs, most likely you just need to rotate by 90 degrees.

Comment: That solved the problem. Haha how simple... I was totally over-thinking it. Thanks!